# Deleting Duplicate rows conditionally in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Input df:

```
C1  C2  C3  C4      C5    C6    C7
12  R11 D21 201901  09
21  R23 D77 201901  21
33  R43 D87 201901  31   D87    Real
33  R43 D87 201901  31   D87   Fetched
57  R12 D87 201901  12   D87   Fetched
```

Expected Output:

```
C1  C2  C3  C4      C5    C6    C7
12  R11 D21 201901  09
21  R23 D77 201901  21
33  R43 D87 201901  31   D87    Real
57  R12 D87 201901  12   D87   Fetched
```

Using R:

In the above dummy table we have 7 Columns and 5 Rows.
The first 6 columns of Row 3 & 4 is the exact same but there is a difference in the 7th Column that is the 3rd Row is Real and Row 4 is Fetched.

How do we remove/drop a row(i.e. Row 4) from this table which is Fetched if it is already Real (i.e Row 3)?

The C6 and C7 for Row 1 and 2 is blank and Row 1 and 2 need not be dropped.

Also, there is absolutely no issues in Row 5 as there is no copy of it's first 6 columns for a Real value.

Comment: Can you reformat so your input df is cut and pasteable, and ideally, formatted as a code block (e.g. the output of `dput()`?  Additionally displaying your input and target df's as tables is also helpful, but not as critical.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a [datastep()](https://libr.r-sassy.org/reference/datastep.html) function from the [libr](https://libr.r-sassy.org) package.

Basically you are stepping through the dataframe row by row and making decisions as you go.  The 'data' variable allows you to dynamically select particular cells in the dataframe.  The 'n.' variable is the row number.

```
  dfin <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 
   12 R11 D21 201901 09 D89 Real
   21 R23 D77 201901 21 D77 Fetched
   33 R43 D87 201901 31 D87 Real 
   33 R43 D87 201901 31 D87 Fetched  
   57 R12 D87 201901 12 D87 Fetched')
  
  # Get a vector of columns to compare
  dsa <- names(dfin[1:6])
  
  dfout <- datastep(dfin, 
                    drop = c("nm"),
                    {
                      
                      
                      # After the first row
                      if (n. > 1) {
                        
                        # Loop through column array
                        for (nm in dsa) {
                          
                          # If any of the first 6 columns don't match
                          # or C7 is equal to Real, keep the row
                          if (data[[n., nm]] != data[[n. - 1, nm]] || 
                              C7 == "Real") {
                            delete <- FALSE
                            break
                          } else {
                            
                            delete <- TRUE 
                            
                          }
                          
                        }
                        
                      } else {
                        
                        # Keep first row by default
                        delete <- FALSE 
                      }
                      
                    })
  
  # See results of datastep
  dfout
  #   C1  C2  C3     C4 C5  C6      C7 delete
  # 1 12 R11 D21 201901  9 D89    Real  FALSE
  # 2 21 R23 D77 201901 21 D77 Fetched  FALSE
  # 3 33 R43 D87 201901 31 D87    Real  FALSE
  # 4 33 R43 D87 201901 31 D87 Fetched   TRUE
  # 5 57 R12 D87 201901 12 D87 Fetched  FALSE
  
  
  # Filter out rows flagged for deletion
  res <- dfout[dfout$delete == FALSE, names(dfout)[1:7]]
  res
  #   C1  C2  C3     C4 C5  C6      C7
  # 1 12 R11 D21 201901  9 D89    Real
  # 2 21 R23 D77 201901 21 D77 Fetched
  # 3 33 R43 D87 201901 31 D87    Real
  # 5 57 R12 D87 201901 12 D87 Fetched
```

Comment: I have plugged the logic in as it seems good for the use case. But, unfortunately it has been tremendously slow.

Comment: Your logic gave : Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)

Comment: 40000000 Rows approx.

Comment: Oh. Then you shouldn't use a libr datastep for this.  Not sure how to do it in R.  SAS would be no problem. Or even c++.  R is not very good at comparing rows.  Maybe someone else has an idea.

Comment: The pipeline has been built over R. So, I cannot move to other env.

Comment: Can you use Rcpp?  This is a package that allows you to run C++ code from R.  If you can use it, I can write a function for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using `dplyr`. I'm grouping by all the columns prior to `C7` (Assuming that's how a record is uniquely identified), then keeping either the one where `C7 == "Real"` or the entire group if it contains only one record. This *will* cause issues for you if there are groups where `C7` is NA *and* "Fetched", but there is no "Real" record.

```r
input <- read.table(
  header = TRUE, 
  text = "C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 
          12 R11 D21 201901 09 D89 NA
          21 R23 D77 201901 21 D77 NA
          33 R43 D87 201901 31 D87 Real 
          33 R43 D87 201901 31 D87 Fetched  
          57 R12 D87 201901 12 D87 Fetched"
)

output <- input %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(C7 == "Real" | n() == 1)


print(output)

# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Groups:   C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6 [4]
#       C1    C2    C3       C4    C5    C6   C7     
#    <int> <chr> <chr>    <int> <int> <chr>   <fct>  
#  1    12   R11   D21   201901     9   D89   NA     
#  2    21   R23   D77   201901    21   D77   NA     
#  3    33   R43   D87   201901    31   D87   Real   
#  4    57   R12   D87   201901    12   D87   Fetched
```